# Non-destructive spl_autoload_register

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm wanting to use the dynamic loading of classes via spl_autoload_register in a wordpress plugin i'm developing but the problem is it can't interfere with pre-existing implementations of this feature. In my initial attempt:

```
// register an autoloader function for template classes
spl_autoload_register ( 'template_autoloader' );

function template_autoloader ( $class ) {
    include LG_FE_DIR . "/includes/chart_templates/class.{$class}.php";
}
```

seems to work in loading my own classes but at the same time causes tons of errors from other plugins that apparently were also using the spl_autoload_register feature.

Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, i've improved my situation a lot by adding the call to spl_autoload_register as part of the "init" hook which I guess allows for most of the static requires/includes to be executed before I run my autoloader. Is this considered the "right way" (or at least an "acceptable way") of doing this in a plugin?

Comment: You could perhaps include some condition within the autoloader; for example, if your classes have a common prefix and that matches the `$class` provided.

Comment: What types of errors are you getting from the other plugins?

Comment: Example errors are mainly of this variety: Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening '/wp-content/plugins/lg-frontend-classes/includes/chart_templates/class.AppLogger.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php') in /wp-content/plugins/lg-frontend-classes/index.frontend.php on line 59

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe I have a reasonable solution now but open to other's opinions. My solution is to have the template loader function test for the existence of the file first. I have also elected to continue to hook into the "init" hook so static includes / requires are loaded first (or at least most of them). The function now looks like this:

```
add_action ( 'init' , 'class_loader' );

function class_loader () {
    // register an autoloader function for template classes
    spl_autoload_register ( 'template_autoloader' );
}

function template_autoloader ( $class ) {
if ( file_exists ( LG_FE_DIR . "/includes/chart_templates/class.{$class}.php" ) ) 
    include LG_FE_DIR . "/includes/chart_templates/class.{$class}.php";

}
```

Comment: This is what I was going to suggest based on the errors you were encountering.  Since you only want to autoload your own classes, you should check that the files exist first before trying to include them.  The spl autoloader will continue to call the other registered autoloaders until one is able to load the required class.

Comment: Yes this was definitely "drew inspired". Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Can you tell me why you wrap your class_loader function in the add_action function? When I do this it does not work for me, but it does work when I only code the spl_autoload_register. Thanks.

Comment: @marczoid the add_action() function is if you're working in a wordpress environment only. This function allows you to hook into the right part of code execution to do certain things (in this to register an autoloader). Sorry I probably should have been more clear about that.